# Local Rindler coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

According to [arXiv:1607.07506](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.07506), in equation (3.10), any Riemannian manifold can be locally endowed with a local Rindler coordinate, such that the metric is locally given by

$$d s^{2}=d r^{2}-r^{2} d \tau^{2}+\left(\gamma_{m n}+r e^{\pm \tau} K_{m n}^{\pm}+\cdots\right) d y^{m} d y^{n}$$
where the manifold is $d$-dimensional $K^{\pm}$ is the extrinsic curvature of the codimension 2 surface with respect to the normals corresponding to $r$ and $\tau$, respectively. Does anyone know how to prove this?